# Как сделать много подобных друг другу страниц в html?

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Собираюсь сделать сайт по типу Википедии. На каждой странице есть индивидуальный заголовок и текстовый параграф.

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы не приходилось для каждый страницы копировать html код, а просто прописывать заголовок и текст

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы не приходилось для каждый
> страницы копировать html код, а просто прописывать заголовок и текст

Самое правильное - использовать [CMS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC).
Если же религия или иные причины это запрещают можно поиграться с [SSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) *(потом понять, что необходимо использовать движок и всё делать заново)*